# Use absolute path to reference a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Not sure if it's possible but can I use absolute path to register a user control on a page?

The reason I want to do this is we have like 50 websites that we need to use the same user control in them.

If not what about loading the user control form the code.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Are these web sites, or web application projects? Also, user controls are meant to be a simple way to reuse some markup and a little logic. They may not be flexible enough for your needs. Consider converting the control into a full custom control. These are made to be used in many projects, just like the built-in controls are.

Comment: @MarkM It says invalid relative path and doesn't build.

Comment: @JohnSaunders These are very old web sites built in .net 2, custom control is also a good idea, I probably try that. Thanks

Comment: If they're old, then I wouldn't do anything radical to them. They already have server controls on them (the built-in ones), so turn your user control into a custom control and use that. See https://www.google.com/search?q=converting+a+user+control+into+a+custom+control

Comment: Yeah that's  good idea, I think I can use the dll that way, I'll try that. Thank you!